# Arcgis split(Cut) feature sample codes in Android sdk

Tags: java, android, android-studio, arcgis, esri

I am developing a mobile application in Android Studio. And here I need to cut a polygon or line features in Arcgis, I came to know that `cut(Geometry geometry, Polyline cutter)` method is used to cut a polygon or polyline in Arcgis. But I didn't find any sample code on this "cut method"
ie, Cuts geometry with cutter.

The cutter and geometry's spatial references must match.
A touch is considered to be a cut (applies when cutting a Polyline).
Can anyone please tell me how to do this...

Thank you.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). And more importantly, please read [Stack Overflow question checklist](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922). You might also want to learn about [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/156810/204922)